# About clock cycles executed

Tags: cpu

i have a pretty basic  question, but for example a cpu clock at 3ghz, does that mean it can do 3 billion cycles per second, or does it every second always will make since 3 billion cycles?

Comment: It means that it will make 3 billion cycles per second

Comment: Its not necessary that in all clock cycles there will be instructions executing, though, if that is what you meant.

Comment: oh yes,my question is whether necessarily all clock cycles need to be executed?

Comment: What can happen: 1. The clock rate changes. 2. The CPU cannot do any instructions because it waits for something to happen. 3. The CPU has been stopped momentarily. All usually done to save power.